# How can I change a list of plain lines into headlines/TODO items?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

If I paste in a block of text composed of separated lines, is there any way to convert each of those lines into either headlines or TODO list items?  So:

```
item
item
item
```

becomes:

```
* item
* item
* item
```

without my having to type [Meta][Return] at the begging of each line?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With a default `org-mode` configuration, select your lines up to and including the newline at the end of the last line, and do `M-x org-toggle-heading`. With a prefix argument, it tells `org-mode` how many levels in it should make the heading (`C-u 4 M-x org-toggle-heading`)

Comment: This command is bound to `C-c *`. A similar command turns lines into plain list items (bound to `C-c -`.

Answer (score 2):

For example with following command:

```
M-x query-replace-regex RET ^\(.*\)$ RET * \1 RET
```

Comment: No facny org-mode way then?  I just have to come up with a good regexp-replace and bind it somewhere?

Comment: really don't know... never converted a lot of documents into .org format

Answer (score 2):

Select your three lines, and while your cursor is on the first column of the fourth line type <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>.
This calls the `string-rectangle` to insert the string `*[space]` in the vertical selection delimited by the mark and the cursor (i.e., the first column).
<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> is a very useful command when editing aligned text.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the line prefix from a [Workflowy](https://workflowy.com/) export (0-n leading spaces followed by a single `-`):

```
M-x replace-regexp RET ^ *- RET \,(make-string (length \&) ?*)
```